# Are there any downsides to floating click lock floors versus traditional nail down floors when both are full wood?

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor

I'm researching flooring and have decided *against* laminate and engineered in favor of full wood flooring.

I have a choice between a **solid** bamboo floating click lock floor and a **solid** bamboo traditional nail down floor.  (Neither are engineered).  They will be laid on 3/4 inch OSB ( Oriented Strand Board ) sub flooring.

Everything negative I'm reading about click lock flooring has to do with the fact that usually they're engineered (and impossible to finish more than once at best).

So my question is **are there any negatives to the floating click lock architecture itself?**  In other words, **why would I opt for a more difficult nail down flooring in this scenario?**

Comment: A floating floor is often used when the thermal expansion characteristics of the flooring are different from that of the subfloor material. Regarding subfloor - use decent plywood instead of OSB.

Comment: Is there a difference in the thickness of the 2 types of flooring?

Comment: @JohnSmith No, they are both 3/4 inch

Comment: Then @DMoore has the best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both are installed correctly then there isn't a ton of difference.

But the small difference - in that the floating can slightly buckle in some areas due to humidity and temp - makes nailing down the choice.  Really floating should be used if installing on slab, if you used a ton of floor leveler, or mixed surfaces.  A far as the install nailing down requires a gun but it is actually easier then glueing everything together.